# Change Linphone audio codec (sipdotnet)

Tags: c#, audio, sip, codec, linphone

I already configured the SIP client and enabled the codecs there, but now I need to use Linphone to make and receive calls with the audio codec G.729 AND G.711 and disable all the others. I downloaded the source code from [this link](https://github.com/bedefaced/sipdotnet) and I need to change the default audio codec but I can not even find anything related to do this in the code. Any help is appreciated... Thanks in advance... (I do NOT want to manipulate this configuration manually, I need it done by coding)